# How to get a element from a Enumerable to an bool variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table with 12 bit columns and I want to get one value into a boolean variable. I'm using Dapper and SQL Server.

```
|PerQuartos|PerVizualizarQuartos|Utilizador|
|  true    |       true         | admin    |
|  false   |      false         | frontdesk|
|          |                    |          |
|          |                    |          |
```

Code:

```
string sql = "SELECT PerQuartos, PerVizualizarQuartos, PerEditarQuartos, PerReservas, PerVizualizarReserva, PerAdicionarReserva, PerRemoverReserva, PerEditarReserva, PerHistorico, PerCheckIn, PerCheckOut,PerListagem FROM dbo.LoginTable WHERE Utilizador = @Utilizador;";

        bool PerQuartos, PerVizualizarQuartos, PerEditarQuartos, PerReservas, PerVizualizarReserva, PerAdicionarReserva, PerRemoverReserva, PerEditarReserva, PerHistorico, PerCheckIn, PerCheckOut, PerListagem;
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel")))
        {
            var permission = connection.Query<Utilizadores>(sql, new { Utilizador = Global.utilizador });
            PerQuartos = permission.Select(r => r.PerQuartos); //I want to add each column value to each specific bool variable but this code gives me error...

        }
```

Note: Query data type "Utilizadores" is different from sql query parameter "Utilizador"..

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => (r.PerQuartos >> x) & 1)

Comment: that didnt work, it says that `PerQuarto` doesnt exist...

Comment: PerQuartos = permission.Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => (r.PerQuartos >> x) & 1) );

Comment: @jdweng This doesn't work because `PerQuartos` is a type bool variable

Comment: Where are the 10 columns coming from?  Is PerQuarto an array?  Then instead of shifting you want r.PerQuartos[x] or .PerQuartos[.Skip(x).Take(1)

Comment: I would strongly suggest putting those `bool`s into a class, then you can just `Query<MyClass>(...`

Comment: @Charlieface I do have those booleans in a class and i'm calling it in `Query<Utilizadores>` but I want to get the value of them from the database and put each column value from a specific row into a separate variable
Example: Column `PerQuartos` has a value of `true` in row 1 and I want to get that value into `bool PerQuarto`. Then I want to do the same for all my columns

Comment: I could do `ExecuteScalar` to get these values one by one, but I would have hundred lines of code and I want to do this in a cleaner way

Comment: I'm confused: doesn't your ORM (is it Dapper?) do that mapping for you? You just `select` the columns you need in SQL, and they are copied into those fields by the mapper.